# linux block size - different in different places

Tags: linux, hard-drive

When I'm checking block size via: blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda I'm getting:
4096
But when I use 
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/physical_block_size
or
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/logical_block_size 
I'm getting 512. Is it normal? Is it ok to have such difference, or it may have impact on performance/hdd lifetime? Additionally I can see:
blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1
1024
So which one is effective block size? Does rest of them means something?

Comment: Why worry about it?  Just align everything to 1MB chunks.  That is a nice round number that covers most devices, and RAID chunks.  Most modern partition tools will do this by default.

Comment: This is what i get after instalation without any manual changes and just make me suspicious. So should I worry about that and change this 512 ? Is is even possible to change if its physical block size?

Comment: No, it isn't possible to change any of that.  The only impact it would have would be if you miss-aligned your filesystem.